# Which method to use for RESTFUL method to get a form

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am aware about some of the most common methods used such as POST,GET,PUT, UPDATE, DELETE...

However I am struggling to understand how to achieve this in a non hacky way.

```
GET   /product  // get a list of products
POST  /product  // update product
PUT   /product  //
DELETE /product //
```

My problem is how do I deal with forms?

What method should I use?

So the question is, I would like to use `/product` to get form, then use post/put to update.

How do you guys deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restful is about resource, think of Product as a resource and POST is to create a resource.

Is a Form a resource in your case ( Would you create or delete a form) ?, If yes, there should be a GET /product-form for getting the form. Otherwise, if the form itself is not a resource, getting a page with a form is like getting a homepage, nothing to do with REST and the Method is most likely GET

Comment: no my form is more like to create the resource using a web page...
So I should create the rest in a seperate folder like API, then create another folder for web manipulation?

Is this correct?

Comment: You can do it that way. Restful applies to an API in most cases. For normal page rendering, go back to traditional development practices.

Answer (score 0):

A form is no resource in the REST sense because it does not correspond to anything in the server state. A form is a UI component of a client.

You should separate REST resources and the methods that handle them from code that delivers client UI.